# WPF Converter problem

Tags: wpf

So I have an object that implements INotifyPropertyChanged, and I have a property that when it changes, it call the PropertyChanged event all right, but when I use a converter like this:

```
        <Image Grid.Column="0">
            <Image.Source>
                <Binding Path="IsInstrumentStatusOk" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                    <Binding.Converter>
                        <converters:BooleanToImageConverter 
                            ImagePathIfFalse="/Images/InstrumentStatusBar/Instrument_Status_Alarm.png"
                            ImagePathIfTrue="/Images/InstrumentStatusBar/Instrument_Status_OK.png" />
                    </Binding.Converter>
                </Binding>
            </Image.Source>
        </Image>
```

For some reason it doesn't update it, and it doesn't call the converter. If I use it like normally

```
Source="{Binding MyProperty, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"
```

It works, but I don't want to use it like that because I have a bunch of converters that I want to use with different images. Any idea why it doesn't update?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting `UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"` in your XAML. This means when the *target property* changes the value should update back to the source. Obviously nothing is ever changing the `Image::Source` property.

Just remove the `UpdateSourceTrigger` setting altogether and you should be fine.

Comment: This didn't do it either, I had to take the Converter and put it in the resource, then reference to it as a StaticResource. It's weird, I have no idea why it wasn't working.

Comment: That is very strange. There's no reason I can think of that it shouldn't work inline like that.

Comment: Ok, so I tried it again, this time it worked. Maybe I'm not using something I was using before? No idea. Thanks for the answer.